# Visual Studio 2010 Prevent Build log polling

Tags: visual-studio-2010, logging, build, continuous-integration, polling

I am running into a problem with viewing the build logs while a build is in progress.
The build is being run on a seperate (continious integration build) machine and we are using VS2010 and Team Foundation Server to manage the build from our development client machines.

The problem is that VS2010 will poll for the logs on the build server and update approx every 30 seconds. The solutions that are being built are pretty big and there are a lot of them. They generate a lot of warnings and logs at the moment which bloat the log considerably. Because of this it is nearly impossible to use VS2010 to view the build log until after the build has completed which is approx 85 minutes.

Obviously - a solution would be to fix up all the warnings, but I was wondering if there is a way to prevent the build log viewer from polling - just list all the detail until a 'refresh' is requested or even a way to extend the poll to say every 5 minutes would work for me.

I understand that the build log no longer gets written out to disk in VS2010 - so I can't access it unless I go through the Build Explorer.

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated!
Jay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, please have a look at this useful post written by [Jason Prickett](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2011/08/15/tfs-2010-overriding-build-settings.aspx) You will be able to change the polling interval by adding a DWROD 'ReportPollingInterval' at HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0\TeamFoundation in the registery. Values to the DWord are assigned in milliseconds, so 30000 would mean 30 seconds.

Also consider installing VS 2010 SP1 on your machine, the SP1 has addressed a lot of performance issues with the build summary page.

Bounce back if you have any follow up questions.

Comment: Hi Tarun, sorry for the late reply - this post is exactly what I was looking for. I have set the interval to 5 minutes and I can actually read the build log now! I am using VS2010 SP1 - the problem was that the build is huge and there are in excess of 25000 tests which add to the log. I would have given you a vote up, but my rep isn't high enough to do that yet Im afraid!